# Accessing controller in Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, token

I am creating an Interceptor that adds/refreshes authentication tokens. Here is some code:

```
a.service('APIInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $location, $window,     $injector, authService) {
....
service.responseError = function (response) {
    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (response.status === 406 && response.data === "Unauthenticated Token.") {
        tokenRefreshing().then(function (res) {                
            return $http(executeRequest(response.config));
        });
    }
};
```

Where function **tokenRefreshing** gets and stores a new token. I am successfuly retrying the lost request by doing:

```
return $http(executeRequest(response.config));
```

But my problem is: how am I going to provide results of the retried request back to a controller that placed the failed request?

Thanks